# HTML5 video tag for Opera Mini

Tags: html, video, opera, opera-mini

Question for the video tag, the following code works for every browsers expect opera mini, any ideas why? i don't even see a video frame when i view the page under my iphone and ipad with opera mini.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<h1>Test Page</h1>

<body>

    <video id="movie" width="320" height="240" preload controls>

        <source src="Untitled.m4v" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />

        <source src="iStock_000010231386HD720.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>

        <source src="Untitled.webm" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>

    </video>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opera Mini isn't a browser in the classic sense:

From http://www.opera.com/mobile/specs/:

> Opera Mini always uses Opera’s advanced server compression technology
>   to compress web content before it gets to a device. The rendering
>   engine is on Opera’s server.

Which is why it won't support the video tag.

Comment: Thanks totally understand now!

Answer (score 4):

Opera mini for iPhone simply does not support html5, thereby it will not display your video.

Also see: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/ and http://forum.brightcove.com/t5/General-Development/html5-on-Opera-mini-browser-iphone/td-p/5341